# Logger output to string

Tags: java, android, junit

I'm pretty new to java and my question is probably very noobish, but I can't figure it out.

I'm having a `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());`

And I want to get the output of that logger as a string. For example when I do

```
logger.info("Some message"); 
logger.warning(" Some warning");
```

I want to get a String someString = "Some message SomeWarning"

I'm looking for something similar to

```
ByteArrayOutputStream loggerContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(loggerContent));
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_1);
tv.setText(loggerContent.toString());
```

But I'm failing to achieve it. Is it possible and how?

EDIT: I want that string to be used in another activity to show it on screen.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Do you want to have that String inside the app you are logging from? Or do you want to get the log output of let's call it "app#1" in "app#2"?

Comment: You can change your log4j to print log to the file as well.

Comment: I want that string to be used in another activity to show it on screen.

Comment: You could create your own [`Handler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) and use that to build the string.

Comment: Can you give me example? I tried earlier with:
ByteArrayOutputStream loggerContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream prStr = new PrintStream(loggerContent);
StreamHandler streamHandler = new StreamHandler(prStr, new SimpleFormatter());
Didn't work.

Comment: Never mind. That works. Just needed to .flush() the Handler. :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream loggerContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
PrintStream prStr = new PrintStream(loggerContent); 
StreamHandler streamHandler = new StreamHandler(prStr, new SimpleFormatter());
```

I tried that before I posted here and couldn't get the result. It actually works, but I had to `.flush()` the StreamHandler before trying loggerContent.toString().
Thanks for the responses guys. :)